# Whitespace error on csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

Here is my rake task for the csv file:

```
task priceupdate: :environment do
  csvtoopen = open('http://www.someurlhere.com/feed.csv')
  csv = CSV.foreach(csvtoopen, :headers=>true)
  csv.each do |row|
    #Stuff to do with rows here
  end
end
```

When I try and run this I get this error:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.
```

My work around was this method.

```
csv = CSV.parse(csvtoopen, :headers=>true, quote_char: "\x00")
```

I'm under the impression it move things to a new cell on commas? The issue is I have events coming back with commas. So is there another work around?

Here's the csv file:

http://api.viagogo.net/feeds/ukeventfeed.csv

Sam